# Will I permanently lose P.T. if I uninstall it?

Tags: ps4, pt

I have P.T. installed on my PS4, but I am worried if I delete it. Since P.T. was removed from the PlayStation Store, if I uninstall it, will I be able to reinstall it at a later date?

Comment: You are very lucky to have gotten the demo. I am truly envious. T_T

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't delete P.T.! If you uninstall it from your PS4, you will **not** be able to reinstall it normally.

[Here](http://www.polygon.com/2015/5/7/8564283/opinion-konami-pt-removal-just-made-p-t-one-of-the-greatest-games-of-all-time) is an article describing how, even though it seems like you would be able to redownload later, you cannot.

That said, it looks like there is a somewhat questionable method to redownload it if you do uninstall it, described [here](http://www.polygon.com/2015/12/16/10296546/pt-hideo-kojima-silent-hills-re-download-ps4), but I highly recommend keeping it, just in case this doesn't work.

Comment: Is this really true that this can happen?

Comment: Can confirm. Uninstalled my copy. Regret it now. T_T

Comment: @TimmyJim yes, it was a big deal when it first got pulled from the store. Many users (Fluttershy included, RIP) were horrified to find they couldn't re download it. Similar to when Flappy Bird got pulled, people who had PT installed after it was pulled sold their PS4s at exorbitant prices since it had one of the remaining downloads of PT still on it. Someone's selling theirs on Amazon, [here](https://www.amazon.com/PS4-Silent-Hills-P-T/dp/B00XELDUT0)... This was part of the Konami/Hideo Kojima dispute I'm sure you've heard about (it affected MGSV as well).

Comment: It might be worth backing it up on a separate (external) HDD as well, if you can.

Comment: @user1306322, I meant "NO" as in "NO DON'T" not as in "NO YOU CANT"...

Comment: I only hope nobody misinterprets your phrasing.

Comment: How did they not get sued for this?

Comment: @Mehrdad who? Konami? PT stands for Playable Teaser. This was 100% free content; it was basically a demo but even less. Because no one paid for it, it's 100% legal for them to refuse access to people. It's just that people who never got rid of it still had/have it. There's nothing to sue over.

Comment: @Vemonus: Ahh, sorry, I didn't know much about the game... I read [this article](http://www.polygon.com/2015/5/7/8564283/opinion-konami-pt-removal-just-made-p-t-one-of-the-greatest-games-of-all-time) which said Konami "revoked that license for every single person on Earth", and that made me think users had purchased a license or something. If it was free then never mind, that's unfortunate!

Comment: @Vemonus That's not how contract law works. The promises in the license agreement matter, not whether you paid or not.

Comment: Might I suggest using ***YES!!!*** instead of ***NO!!!*** to avoid confusion? :P

Comment: @user1306322 The OP title asks one question, while the question body asks the opposite question. There's no way to avoid the confusion. Better not to say yes or no.

Comment: @Rhymoid Agreed, but (I assume) nothing about the license forces Konami to *continue* offering the license or content. But it might be unreasonable for them to force users to uninstall it.

Comment: @Vemonus Is there a way I can delete my saves but not delete the game?

Comment: @CamouflagedCow I have no idea, I don't have the game :/  surely there is a way, though

Comment: @Vemonus If you know of a way to back-up P.T., post it here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/290532/can-you-back-up-individual-games-rather-than-my-entire-hardrive